# With UIScrollView zoom images in layout frame

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have create an app in Xcode.

In my apps I require a functionality that has several images in uiscroll view.

I cannot zoom images in scroll view. How i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put your image view inside scroll view, and make  user interaction as well as multiple touch enable in each, now

provide following setting to your scroll view:

```
//Pinch Zoom Stuff
imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
imageScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageScrollView.delegate = self;
imageScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Then implement Following methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
if (scrollView.zoomScale!=1.0) 
{
    // Not zoomed, let the scroll view scroll
    imageScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

}
else 
{
    // Zooming, disable scrolling
    imageScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
}

- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

return imageView;
}
```

Comment: @Dimple Panchal: that's why it's here.. :)