# Zooming in UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

can someone help me on doing zooming with the UIScrollView?

I am trying to add the three images retrieved from an URL and display it using a UIScrollView. I can do the display part but the zooming is not working. I hope someone can show me some lights.

My .h file

```
@interface TestScrollViewViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{

IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
UIImageView *subview;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *subview;

@end
```

the .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *page1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.com/001.jpg"]]];
    UIImage *page2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.com/002.jpg"]]];
    UIImage *page3 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.com/003.jpg"]]];


    NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: page1, page2, page3, nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
    self.scrollView.delegate=self;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];   

    [subview release];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * images.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

}
```

and this is the viewForZoomingInScrollView method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.scrollView;
}
```

Really hope someones can help. Thanks.

Lawrence

Comment: If Problem still persist refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566996/with-uiscrollview-zoom-images-in-layout-frame/6567199#6567199

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace

```
return self.scrollView;
```

With

```
return subview;
```

Comment: i too think the same +1 for that :)

Answer (score 4):

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.scrollView;
}
```

That's what's wrong. You can't return the scroll view itself here, you must return it's subview that you want to zoom.

Comment: Thanks guys for your kind reply and I can do the zooming now, but only works with the last picture, any idea why this would happen and how to fix it?